# What is a word or phrase meaning "ever so slightly" but with less emphasis on slightly?

Tags: phrase-requests

Imagine you have a serendipitous encounter with an old friend and they made your day "that much more" interesting. What is a good phrase meaning *incrementally better* but perhaps a little more sophisticated than *that much more*—something one would be more inclined to use as a compliment?

Comment: I think that "more much interesting* is a far better compliment than "a bit more interesting." Do you like your friends or not? However, "a bit more" may be what you are looking for.

Comment: The reason for nuance is that the encounter happened at an event and it would be arguably rude to suggest that the encounter was more interesting than the event, if that makes any sense. But, maybe I just lack a certain level of charm...

Comment: It would depend on the event, I suppose. A wedding? -- yes. A conference? -- no.

Comment: A wedding, indeed (;

Comment: You are excused. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Catching up with you was *[the icing on the cake](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/icing-on-the-cake)*.

From [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/icing-on-the-cake):

> **the icing on the cake**
>
> something that makes a good situation even better:
>
> *I was just content to see my daughter in such a stable relationship but a grandchild, that really was the icing on the cake.*

Answer (score 0):

One phrase that comes to mind is "add color". If you *add color* to something you make it more interesting without diminishing the value of the original thing.